# How to open a file in my resources dir in a way that it's accessible after sbt-assembly?

Tags: java, scala, jar, sbt, sbt-assembly

My Scala application makes use of Tototoshi's ScalaCSV library and as such I need to open a CSV file I placed under `/src/main/resources/data.csv`. I access it this way:

```scala
val file = getClass.getResource("/data.csv").getFile
CSVReader.open(file)
...
```

This set-up works perfectly when I run my application under IntellijIDEA but it stops working once I package it with `sbt-assemby` and I get this error instead:

```
file:/home/.../target/scala-2.11/projectx-assembly-0.0.1.jar!/data.csv (No such file or directory)
```

How can I access the contents of this file in a way that it works from both the IDE and the assembled jar file?

Comment: That looks odd, did you check that the 'data.csv' is in the resulting jar file? and that it is at the root of the jar file

Comment: In the jar file I can see (through `jar tf projectx-assembly-0.0.1.jar`) that the `data.csv` file is there. It appears in the _root_ of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you package it the csv-file will reside in the jar archive; right? Then you can't access it directly as a file. Instead you need to ask for a stream:

```
val stream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/data.csv")
```

Possibly you need to wrap the stream in a InputStreamReader for the CSVReader to accept it:

```
val reader = new InputStreamReader(stream)
CSVReader.open(reader)
```

Comment: @hanbzu maybe i'm missing something but isn't the name of the reading function `open` instead of `read`?

Comment: @Absurd-Mind you are completely right, it is `CSVReader.open(reader)`. I've corrected the question now. **I got it working** with @thoredge's approach. But as he said, **I had to wrap the stream** in an _InputStreamReader_ as follows: `val reader = new InputStreamReader(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/data.csv"))` and then I used that reader with the CSV reader `CSVReader.open(reader)`